# How to redirect to next page When Two Strings are equal

Tags: ios, objective-c, redirect, if-statement

I need When Two NSStrings are Equal It's Navigate Next ViewControl and Two NSStrings are Not Equal just show Alert.

```
NSString* foo = @"Foo";
NSString* bar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",foo];
if([foo isEqualToString:bar])
    //it's redirect nextViewControl
else
     UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message!" message:@"NOt Valid" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
```

So Please give me any idea about Redirecting to NextViewControl.I know when Button is Clicked to Redirect to NextViewControl.

```
 SecondViewController *second=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[second setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL ];
```

But I don't know how to redirect to ViewControl based on if Condition .
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: It would always be same. Implementation would be same for both scenarios.

Comment: How you designed your nextviewcontroller programatically or in storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
    NSString* foo = @"Foo";
    NSString* bar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",foo];
    if([foo isEqualToString:bar])
    {
        SecondViewController *second=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil]; 
        [second setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
        [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:NULL ];
    }
    //it's redirect nextViewControl
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message!" message:@"NOt Valid" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    }
```

I hope this useful for you.

Comment: Please tell me with out Storyboard how to Redirect

Comment: This is not a storyboard coding . this is a simple method of present your viewcontroller with modeltransitionstyle .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 NSString* foo = @"Foo";
    NSString* bar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",foo];
    if([foo isEqualToString:bar])
    {
        ViewController *second=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [second setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

        [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil ];

        NSLog(@"hie");
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message!" message:@"NOt Valid" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString *str1 = @"Next";
    NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str1];

```
if ([str1 isEqualToString:str2])
{
    SecondViewController *scrSecond = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:scrSecond animated:YES];
}
```